# Django stylesheet loads but doesn't apply?

Tags: css, django, stylesheet

I'm using Django and the static media app, along with Nginx. For some reason the external stylesheet doesn't apply itself. However, when I click on it in the source file, it does indeed load the style.css file.

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}" />

<!-- EVEN THIS DOESN'T LOAD HERE
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/static/css/style.css"  />
-->

</head>
<body>
<!-- some stuff -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post an example of some of the css and html it should affect but isn't? Ideally the entire source. Cleared cached versions/etc I'm assuming too?

Answer (score 0):

Check the error log of Nginx (error.log). Sometimes it is on the path '/usr/local/nginx/logs/error.log'.

Load the page and then make in command line: "tail -n 20 /usr/local/nginx/logs/error.log". You can see the path on which Nginx tries to load your css file and error message if there is no such file on the path.

**The pass and the name of file are both case-sensetive**.

If your css file loads normally (you can see it, for example, by using firebug) then it is not a problem of Django. Definitely there is a mistake in HTML and/or in CSS.